# RegEx for capturing every single character except forward slash

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have the following two example strings:

```
"taxonomy": "abc/about_abc/bsc/archive/2009/presentations_dec"

"taxonomy": "about/archive/term"

"taxonomy": "_decommisioned/ntp-server.niehs.nih.gov/htdocs/results_status/resstatf"
```

I have tried with the following RegEx:

```
"taxonomy": "(\w+[^\/])\/?"?
```

The goal is to take each of those strings and explode them onto their own separate lines on the forward slash, so `term1/term2/term3` equals

```
term1
term2
term3
```

I also don't know how many terms there are per line, which is why they are broke up like they are. It could be minimum one, max 7. My fill RegEx looks like this:

```
(    "taxonomy": "(\w+[^\/])?\/?(\w+[^\/])?\/?(\w+[^\/])?\/?(\w+[^\/])?\/?(\w+[^\/])?\/?(\w+[^\/])?\/?(\w+[^\/])?\/?")
```

How do I adjust my capture group to get **everything** except the forward slashes?

Comment: If you want everything, then why even bother with `\w+`? Just do `[^\/]+`  That is the problem in the third input... it has a dot and hyphen which are not satisfying `\w`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, in the third string this part `ntp-server.niehs.nih.gov` which is not matched by `\w`

But you might simplify your expression by matching not a forward slash by using a negated character class and a repeating pattern that match a forward slash and then again 1+ times not a forward slash.

Then you could split your match on a forward slash.

Pattern

```
"taxonomy": "\K[^/\n]+(?:/[^/\n]+)+(?=")
```

**Explanation**

- `"taxonomy":` Match literally
- `"\K` Match double quote and then forget what was matched using `\K`
- `[^/\n]+` Match 1+ times not a forward slash using a negated character class
- `(?:/[^/\n]+)+` Repeating pattern to match `/`, then 1+ times not a `/`
- `(?=")` Positive lookahead to assert what is on the right is a double quote

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/8PLYEz/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/BteJe)

For example, if you use explode in php:

```
$pattern = '~"taxonomy": "\K[^/\n]+(?:/[^/\n]+)+(?=")~';

$strings = [
    '"taxonomy": "abc/about_abc/bsc/archive/2009/presentations_dec"',
    '"taxonomy": "about/archive/term"',
    '"taxonomy": "_decommisioned/ntp-server.niehs.nih.gov/htdocs/results_status/resstatf"'
];

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $match);
    print_r(explode('/', $match[0]));

}
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => abc
    [1] => about_abc
    [2] => bsc
    [3] => archive
    [4] => 2009
    [5] => presentations_dec
)
Array
(
    [0] => about
    [1] => archive
    [2] => term
)
Array
(
    [0] => _decommisioned
    [1] => ntp-server.niehs.nih.gov
    [2] => htdocs
    [3] => results_status
    [4] => resstatf
)
```

Comment: I'm getting errors with that code. Do you mean [^\/\n], escaping the forward slash? I'm using a PCRE regex find replace engine

Comment: If your delimiter for the pattern is `/` then you have to escape the forward slash like `\/`. In my example the delimiter is `~`  so then you don't have to escape it.